# JSON Parsing in Python - help extracting dictionaries inside a list

Tags: python, json

I've searched and there's a similar problem here but the solution states to fix the json. I really cant fix the json produced as its from a REST API.

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "uri": "http://website:6405/biprws/v1/cmsquery?page=1&pagesize=50"
    },
    "first": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "http://website:6405/biprws/v1/cmsquery?page=1&pagesize=50"
        }
    },
    "last": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "http://website:6405/biprws/v1/cmsquery?page=1&pagesize=50"
        }
    },
    "entries": [
        {
            "SI_ID": 31543,
            "SI_NAME": "Some Client",
            "SI_PARENTID": 31414,
            "SI_PATH": {
                "SI_FOLDER_NAME1": "COR OPS",
                "SI_FOLDER_ID1": 31414,
                "SI_FOLDER_OBTYPE1": 1,
                "SI_FOLDER_NAME2": "CLIENT",
                "SI_FOLDER_ID2": 28178,
                "SI_FOLDER_OBTYPE2": 1,
                "SI_NUM_FOLDERS": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to get the folder names from SI_PATH, but that is where I am having issues. I can access "entries" fine as the whole json is considered as a dict, but the problem is after. If I get "entries", its just a list with a len of 1

```
import json

data = json.load(open('file.json'))
print(type(data))
print(data['entries])
print(type(data['entries']))
```

Sample output below:

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>
[{'SI_ID': 31543, 'SI_NAME': 'Some Client', 'SI_PARENTID': 31414, 'SI_PATH': {'SI_FOLDER_NAME1': 'COR OPS', 'SI_FOLDER_ID1': 31414, 'SI_FOLDER_OBTYPE1': 1, 'SI_FOLDER_NAME2': 'CLIENT', 'SI_FOLDER_ID2': 28178, 'SI_FOLDER_OBTYPE2': 1, 'SI_NUM_FOLDERS': 2}}]
```

I can use pandas to put the 'entries' onto a DataFrame and pull in the SI_PATH values, but not sure how to access each of them.

```
f = pd.DataFrame(data['entries'])
print(f['SI_PATH'].values)
```

Output of this:

```
[{'SI_FOLDER_NAME1': 'COR OPS', 'SI_FOLDER_ID1': 31414, 'SI_FOLDER_OBTYPE1': 1, 'SI_FOLDER_NAME2': 'CLIENT', 'SI_FOLDER_ID2': 28178, 'SI_FOLDER_OBTYPE2': 1, 'SI_NUM_FOLDERS': 2}]
```

But unsure as to how to access the items individual from this point. If possible, really want to stick with just importing json.

Comment: `f['SI_PATH'].values[0].keys()` ?

Comment: `print(data['entries'])` print list of entries; `print(data['entries'][0])` print first entry; `for entry in data['entries']: print(entry)` print every entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one item in the list that is `data['entries']`:

```
print(data['entries'][0]['SI_ID'])
```

Prints:

```
31543
```

Comment: shoot. That I didn't think of. Worked though. Now I can just iterate to get the folder names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since it is a list of dict, why not

```
for items in data['entries']:
    print(items.get("SI_ID"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works but for my uses, the one above best suits my need

Comment: looking at it more closely, I'm seeing a need to iterate through data['entries'] to possibly get a list of all tag - value combo.

Comment: It is always a good idea to add a for loop. Also eliminates the possibility where data["Entries"] is blank and [0] is causing you an error.